# In Spark, is there a performance difference between querying DataFrames on CSV and JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV file and a JSON file (each with 5 million rows/records) located on AWS S3. They contain the exact same data, only the format is different.

On an EMR cluster with 10 task nodes, I've started Spark (10 executors, 40 executor cores) and have created two DataFrames: one against the CSV, one against JSON.

Queries against the DF built off the JSON file run 2-3 times faster than like queries against the DF built off the CSV. I have not found any information on performance differences across stored file formats.

*Does anybody have information on why queries against the DF on JSON run faster than the DF on CSV?*

**Code of Dataframe creation below**

*Create DF against JSON file:*

```
val hc_json = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val path_json = "s3://<mybucket>/<myjsonfile>.json"
val df_json = hc_json.read.json(path_json)
df_json.registerTempTable("table_json")
hc_json.sql("Select count(*) from table_json").collect()
```

*Create DF against CSV file:*

(I import the spark-csv package while starting Spark with the following parameter:  --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0)

```
val hc_csv = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val path_csv = "s3://<mybucket>/<mycsvfile>.csv"
val df_csv = hc_csv.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> path,"header"->"false"))
df_csv.registerTempTable("table_csv")
hc_csv.sql("Select count(*) from table_csv").collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no performance difference between DataFrames created using different data sources, it includes JSON, or csv.

Problem is when you call `hc_json.sql` in above snippets you not only execute query but also load data from disk each time query is executed. It means you measure not a query time, but a disk-access + parsing + query. The first* and the last should be more or less the same for JSON and csv but parsing will vary from source to source.

If you want to measure only the actual query time you should cache your data and execute an action to make sure data has been actually loaded. For example

```
df_csv.registerTempTable("table_csv")
sqlContext.cacheTable("table_csv")
hc_csv.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM table_csv").collect()
```

Now data should be loaded and you can expect similar query times.

**Edit** There is actually one more difference here. DataFrame created from JSON source will get correct data types while one from csv, without providing schema or setting `inferSchema` option reads everything as strings.

---

* As pointed out by [kostya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477832/kostya) JSON files are usually smaller. From the other hand JSON, unlike csv, handles sparse date pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I forgot about caching. I knew I could cache the DataFrame but I figure it's better to cache the table after it's registered. I'm not sure it makes much of a difference, though.

Comment: If you want to use `cacheTable`, which is preferred approach then you have register first.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can affect query performance including:

- format of the data
- implementation details of DataFrame's DataSource
- a query itself
- data structure

Using CSV will most likely be faster for most of the queries as the file size is less than JSON and less data needs to be read from the disk. Using parquet file format will likely be even faster because of even smaller file size and faster decoding times.

Queries like (`select count(*) from table_csv`) can run faster with some formats (e.g. parquet) because Spark is smart enough to skip reading data if no columns are requested.

@zero323 suggested to load data in memory first, this will most likely improve query execution speed but it won't work if you do not have enough RAM in your cluster to hold the entire dataset.

Comment: Regarding my file sizes, the JSON (2.1GB) is actually smaller than my CSV (2.6GB). They have the exact same data, just the format is different. My JSON has just one record per line, so it imports via  'hc_json.read.json(path_json)' properly. Can I ask what you meant when you said "smart enough to skip parsing if no columns are requested"? Do you mean at query time?

Comment: It is surprising that your JSON file is smaller, probably the data is not the same. JSON format duplicates field names for each row, while CSV only contains them once as the first line. Files get parsed when a query is executed (if table is not cached).

Comment: _DataSource is smart enough to skip parsing if no colums are requested_ - you're wrong here. `count(*)` is translated  to `count(1)` in non nullable cases by optimizer before query even hits source.

Comment: Regarding csv vs. JSON size is not everything.  Both are not very smart formats, but unlike csv, JSON is standardized and can be efficiently parsed.

Comment: @zero323, I think you are right about me being wrong, though theoretically it is possible ;) Regarding the second point there are no reasons why an efficient CSV parser will be slower than JSON parser.

Comment: About optimizations see [the source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fc27dfbf0f8d3f96c70e27d88f7d0316c97ddb1e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L378). And there are two reasons why JSON parsing can be optimized while csv parsing cannot - being type aware and being restricted. At the end of the day csv parsing is pretty much about handling special cases.

Comment: BTW Regarding types see my edit. Output DFs are not the same here. Anyway, since OP cannot upvote, +1 from my for pointing out difference in the size.